# jQuery: $("#myid").html('<span id="inserted">inserted portion</span>')

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Say I am doing the following manipulation using jQuery:

```
$("#myid").html('<span id="inserted">inserted portion</span>')
```

After doing this operation, if I view the page source, the inserted portion of the HTML (the span tag with id "inserted") is not available there and any further operation I do with $("#inserted") simply fails!

This becomes a major issue when we update (we usually use the jQuery html() method to insert new parts) part of the page by AJAX call and try to do more operations in the updated part.

Please anyone explain what am I missing?

Comment: poor title. you should try naming it something other than a line of code...

Comment: "When I view the page source" — How exactly are you doing that? Also, does the text "inserted portion" appear on the page itself, or does the whole insert fail?

Comment: Provide a more detailed example of your js and html  so we can analyze your code.

Comment: @miss_duke , are you binding...any events for the elements you added dynamically , if they are not working with normal bind use live...

Comment: @duke , did you fix the problem??

Comment: a good title would be something like... `Problems inserting HTML with jQuery` or something...

Comment: @gov, Stackoverflow informed me about your replies only today, I don't know why. I haven't tested your suggestion yet, but it seems your reply is the direct solution of my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whatever events you are binding for id inserted ....use live , this will bind for future html elements or html added at runtime

```
http://api.jquery.com/live/

$('#inserted ').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

Comment: This reply seems the direct solution to my problem (yet to test it anyway). Thanks very much gov.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the page source is just that... the *source*.. which is loaded into the browser.  After the document is loaded, you manipulate the document via the jquery [Document Ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function (executes after all images etc are loaded).

If you want to inspect your modified HTML/CSS/Whatever use a debugging tool such as firebug or the Chrome / Safari developer tools.

If `$("#inserted)` operations are failing I would suggest posting a specific example.  We can't really help you if you don't post any specifics.

Answer (score 2):

If `#myid` exists, then the new element will exist in the document's internal representation in the browser (the "DOM"). It shouldn't show on the "view source", since the source of the page is the original html (and js), but any operation from then on should behave exactly as if it existed in the source.